# Type casting with decorator pattern

Tags: c#, casting, decorator

I have a motor interface and various vendor-specific implementations of the interface.

```
public interface IMotor
{
  void Home();
  void Move();
}

public class VenodorAMotor : IMotor
{
  public void Home()
  { /*home motor*/  }

  public void Move()
  { /*move motor*/  }     
}
```

I'm decorating the IMotor to add some functionality to its home method.

```
public class HomeAdjustmentDecorator : IMotor
{
  private IMotor decoratedMtr;

  public static explicit operator VendorAMotor(HomeAdjustmentDecorator mtr) 
  { return (VendorAMotor)mtr.decoratedMtr; }

  public HomeAdjustmentDecorator(IMotor mtr)
  { 
    if(! mtr is VenodorAMotor)
      throw new Exception("HomeAdjustmentDecorator can only decorate VenodorAMotor objects");
    decoratedMtr = mtr; 
  }

  public void Home()
  {
    decoratedMtr.Home();
    double adjustment = ((VendorAMotor)myMotor).GetHomeAdjustment();//vendor-specific functionality
    Log(adjustment);
  }

  public void Move()
  { decoratedMtr.Move();  }  
}
```

I don't have control of the `VendorAMotor` creation, so I can't easily use inheritance.

The problem is existing code which already casts an undecorated IMotor to its implementing class to get access to other vendor-specific functionality.  The cast fails because HomeAdjustmentDecorator does not inherit VenodorAMotor.

```
IMotor myDecoratedMotor;//Implementation is HomeAdjustmentDecorator composed of VendorAMotor
...
((VendorAMotor)myDecoratedMotor).DoOtherVendorSpecificStuff();
```

I've tried overriding the cast operator as shown, but this doesn't work.  I get an InvalidCastExeption: "Unable to cast object of type 'HomeAdjustmentDecorator ' to type 'VenodorAMotor'."
**Everything compiles fine.  The explicit cast operator override is not executed, a breakpoint does not hit.  The question is, is this cast override not executed?**

The closest I've found a similar question here: 
[Decoration with several interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55166176/decoration-with-several-interface)
but it doesn't quite help.

I think the answer is here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#user-defined-conversions
but I think I'm missing some subtle detail.

Comment: Since the decorator functionality is specific to the `VenodorAMotor` implementation, could you just add the necessary code to the `VenodorAMotor` class instead?

Comment: Assuming `myDecoratedMotor` is `IMotor` and you have no control over `IMotor` there is no way for you to add conversions to it (one can only add conversion to they own class)... So you may want to clarify what exactly you trying to achieve and what you are willing to do to get there...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov; can you please clarify your statement for me:"there is no way for you to add conversions to it (one can only add conversion to they own class)"?  I'm trying to cast an `IMotor`, implementation is `HomeAdjustmentDecorator`, to `VenodorAMotor`, which the `HomeAdjustmentDecorator` is composed of (as an `IMotor`).  I control 'HomeAdjustmentDecorator' and know it is composed of that which I am trying to cast it to.  Thanks!

Comment: @user3532473 I don't get your comment. Based on question it sounded like `IMotor myDecoratedMotor;` - you have no chance to get the cast working based on your constraints... Indeed `HomeAdjustmentDecorator myDecoratedMotor...; ((VenodorAMotor)myDecoratedMotor).DoOtherVendorSpecificStuff();` would work perfectly fine with your code... but than what you trying to ask?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov.  ((VenodorAMotor)myDecoratedMotor).DoOtherVendorSpecificStuff(); does NOT work.  I guess that's exactly what I'm trying to ask - why doesn't it work or what am I missing?  Seems like one of the other pending answers might have it: "Conversion operators would NOT work for interfaces, because at compile time, there is no concrete type to use (by the compiler) to find such operators."

Comment: weichch's answers shows that code compiles perfectly fine when applied to object of type `HomeAdjustmentDecorator` (which what I tried to say with my comment)...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov  Yes, it compiles fine.  But I get invalid cast Exception at runtime, and the override of the cast operator is not executed. Why not?  That's my question.

Comment: @user3532473 you even accepted the answer which shows code where the cast is invoked... I don't know how to clarify that  `HomeAdjustmentDecorator myDecoratedMotor...;` and `IMotor myDecoratedMotor;` are different way to declare a variable and lead to different compiled code (later can't have any custom conversions). Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think casting from an interface to a concrete class for calling a specific method is a bad practice, and as you have seen it already caused problem.

Conversion operators would **NOT** work for interfaces, because at compile time, there is no concrete type to use (by the compiler) to find such operators.

Given you do not have access to source code of `IMotor`, you might want to at least centralize the cast and extend `IMotor` with an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods):

```
public static class MotorExtensions
{
    public static void DoOtherVendorSpecificStuff(this IMotor motor)
    {
        if (motor is HomeAdjustmentDecorator decorator)
        {
            // This calls implicit cast operator
            ((VendorAMotor)decorator).DoOtherVendorSpecificStuff();
            return;
        }

        ((VendorAMotor)motor).DoOtherVendorSpecificStuff();
    }
}
```

And change cast to:

```
IMotor motor = new VendorAMotor();
IMotor decorated = new HomeAdjustmentDecorator(motor);

// Both should work
motor.DoOtherVendorSpecificStuff();
decorated.DoOtherVendorSpecificStuff();
```

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned, it's a bad practice to mix interfaces with type conversion to concrete implementation. 
Note: usually it's ok to check if your object implements one or more other interfaces:

```
if (motor is IDisposable disposable)
    disposable.Dispose();
```

The reason: interfaces exist to define the behaviour of objects. Interfaces are to ensure any implementation will work for your function. When you check for concrete implementation you brake Liskov Substitution Principle.

As for your original question you can define additional interface:

```
public interface IMotorWithVendorStuff: IMotor
{
    DoOtherVendorSpecificStuff();
}
```

and adapter for `VendorAMotor` to implement that interface:

```
public class VendorAMotorAdapter: IMotorWithVendorStuff
{
    // ...
}
```

You should use `IMotorWithVendorStuff` in all places where you cast `IMotor` to `VendorAMotor`.